# How to use properly Spark ML persistency / dataframe write in client mode?

Tags: apache-spark

(Spark versions : 2.x)

When Spark runs in client mode, then the driver is executed on the same JVM that the `submit` command launched: hence when connecting on a remote cluster (for instance in the cloud), the driver might share a totally different `FileSystem` from the workers (the driver might even be in Windows, whereas the workers could run in Linux).

That being said, when serializing an `MLWritable` instance, or just even writing a `DataFrame` with parquet for instance, the driver **must** share the same paths as the workers since it writes the `_SUCCESS` and `_SUCCESS.crc` files. Should I understand that Spark is always meant to have coherency between the driver and workers (which is a pity: it's so much easier to code in client mode for debug, even though it runs in a cluster in the cloud for instance... ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes. Spark uses Hadoop path and they need to be the same on both the driver and the executors for plenty of reasons. The good thing is that it's very easy to implement your own `FileSystem` (according to Hadoop) mais make it work properly.